# Copy file from inside a .war, after deploying to liferay

Tags: liferay, war

I want to copy a configuration file from inside the .war file which is being deployed to a specific folder. The reason is that I want to pick it up and process it afterwards, and I might have multiple files, depending on the number of archives deployed on the server. Is there a way to trigger this action, after Liferay picks up the .war file? If yes, any suggestions how?

p.s. I have 0 experience with Liferay

Comment: Would you please check in direction of using hot deploy listeners(used for deployment/undeployment of war files)? you can check property hot.deploy.listeners in portal.properties ...

Comment: What's the reason for doing this after/during deployment? I'd argue that this is a perfect usecase for any regular configuration management tool and deployment workflow (to have done it before deployment, that is)

Comment: @Kathiriya I had a look at hooks and listeners. Does this only work for hot deploy? (not sure how the customer will deploy the war files)

Comment: @OlafKock this isn't the configuration of the deployment itself. The deployment will extend a settings 'framework' with it's own settings. So the war file will carry setting definition and I want these copied across to a different server.

Comment: run your "settings framework" before you package the war. Deploy the war file with the settings already done.